# Render Error: _firebase.db.collection is not a function. (In '_firebase.db.collection('events'), '_firebase.db.collection' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am using firebase, expo and react native for an app. I am very new to firebase and is trying to create a page of events that take information from firebase firestore. However, I keep running into errors while trying to query from my firestore. Below are two code snippets which I believe the errors lie. First is firebase.js where I handle all firebase related code, second is eventspage.js where it lists all events page.

There is no api key etc from firebase.js as I have intentionally removed them.

[image: This is a picture of my firestore]

```js
// import all functions needed from the SDKS needed
import { firebase } from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import {initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";


import {
  getFirestore, collection, getDocs,
  addDoc,
} from 'firebase/firestore'



// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: FIREBASE_APIKEY,
    authDomain: FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
    projectId: FIREBASE_PROJECTID,
    storageBucket: FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
    appId: FIREBASE_APPID,
    measurementId: FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID,
  }



  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

  const db = getFirestore(app);
  const auth = getAuth(app);

  export {auth, db}
```

Below shows eventspage.js

```js
import React, { useState, setState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import Card from '../components/Card';
import colors from '../config/colors';
import {MaterialCommunityIcons} from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';

import { firestore, collection, doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

import {db} from '../../firebase';

//run: 1
//swim: 2
//cycle: 3

function EventsPage(props) {
    const navigation = useNavigation()

    const eventRef = db.collection('events').doc('event1');
    const snapshot = eventRef.get();
    snapshot.then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
    
    
    
    

    return (

        <ScrollView style = {styles.container}>
            <ImageBackground
                source = {require('../assets/splash-page.jpg')}
                style = {{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
                blurRadius={8}
            >   
            <View style = {styles.closeIcon}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name='arrow-left-bold' color="black" size={35} onPress={() => {
                        navigation.replace("Connect_me")
                  }} />
            </View>
            <View style = {styles.searchIcon}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name='magnify' color="black" size={35} />
            </View>
        <Text style = {styles.text}>EVENTS</Text>
            <View style = {styles.cardContainer}>
            <Card 
                title={'NIKE RUN'}
                subTitle={'Just Run Lah!'}
                image={require('../assets/Nike_KL_Run.jpg')}
                onPress = {() => {
                    navigation.replace("EventsListing_1")
              }}
            />
            
            </View>
            </ImageBackground>
            <Text></Text>
            <Text></Text>
            <Text></Text>
            <Text></Text> 
            <Text></Text>
        </ScrollView>
        // trolling
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        fontSize: 80,
        textAlign:'center',
        paddingBottom: 20,
        color: colors.primary,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    cardContainer: {
        width: '95%',
        alignSelf: 'center'
    },
    closeIcon: {
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingTop: 30,
    }, 
    searchIcon: {
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingTop: 15,
        position: 'relative',
        left: 330,
        bottom: 47
    }
})

export default EventsPage;
```

Please help! If possible, do let me know how to create an events page by querying the data from firestore and displaying them on eventspage.js too! Thanks!

Comment: What is the Firebase version you are using? I guess if it is upgraded to Firebase v9. Then follow the Modular SDK [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) or [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) to get a single or multiple documents from "firebase/firestore" respectively

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at my last comment?

Comment: I have posted an answer below. Let me know if you need any help with your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Modular SDK v9 I guess but still using the syntax of version 8 web sdk to get the data from Firestore. Try reading how to  [upgrade version 8 to Modular SDK documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)

Try refactoring the code like below:

**To get a single document “SF” from a collection :**

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
 
const docRef = doc(db, "cities", "SF");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
 
if (docSnap.exists()) {
  console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
} else {
  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
  console.log("No such document!");
}
```

**To get all documents from a collection :**

```
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
 
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "cities"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

You can learn more about the new syntax in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document)